# Finding mnemonic sentences and acrostics

Tags: search, text, mnemonics

There are many websites with which one can carry out searches to return results with specific constraints from a dictionary with the purpose of solving word puzzles.

But is there a way to search a specific text document, other than a dictionary, so that one can locate meaningful mnemonic sentences from the text of one's choice?

For example, if I want to find a sentence to help me remember the order of a list of letters, M, I, S, S, C, G, which are the first letters of a list of words I need to remember:  Muscular, Infrahyoid, Superior laryngeal, Sternomastoid, Cricothyroid, Glandular, how can I search a text document (or multiple documents) for sentences in which these letters appear as the first letters in the words of that sentence?, in a specified order?

This would allow me to memorize sentences from the text of my choice, which are meaningful and useful, and simultaneously memorize the order of the letters which I need to recall the list of vocabulary words.

Sure, I can generate a mnemonic of random, meaningless words, which would serve the purpose of memory recall just fine.  I might end up with a funny sentence like: "May I Softly Squeeze Charlie's Girl?" to help me remember the above list of words.  However, I would much prefer to find mnemonic sentences from a text of my choice which are personally meaningful to me.

Any suggestions you might have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Make it sound so cool guv'." If you have a favourite text and you know how to read one word at a time, it's not really hard to code.

Comment: Using GREP on the command line: `grep -i -E "m\w+ i\w* s\w+ s\w+ c\w+" *.txt` found this quote ".. merge in some sense creates chains .." as the *only* hit in several dozens of megabytes of plain text. Just to give you a perspective on what to expect.

Comment: wow, I guess I didn't realize how hard it could be to find matches.  Interesting.  Thank you.

Comment: If my GREP worked for you I'd be happy to submit it as an answer. I'll also explain it some more.